# Developing an enhanced Duplicate Management feature, as standard as possible

Tags: lightning-aura-components, duplicate-management

Due to business needs, we are currently using a slightly different system than the standard for duplicate detection, but, we would still like to use as much as possible of the out-of-the-box functionality.

As of now, **we have developed some functionality in the Lead and Contact triggers which inserts DuplicateRecordItems and DuplicateRecordSets** depending on if we consider them duplicates or not. We associate the sets to a standard DuplicateRule called `Apex_Duplicates`, for the sake of assigning it to one, but the rule is *associated* to Accounts.

In order to visualize duplicates, we can create reports and dashboards on *dupItems*, but **we would also like to take advantage of the standard `Potential Duplicates` Lightning Component. Is there any way to do this, via configuration or development?**

I haven't found much documentation on the component, so I don't really know how it functions internally. I don't know if it's required for our dup rule to be associated to the specific Duplicate Rule, or if it's done by some other way.

Furthermore, **is it possible to still get the duplicate warning which Duplicate rules give you on insert** or is that funcionality related to the duplicate rules and not to the DuplicateRecordItems/Sets? If not (which I assume), which would be the easiest way to provide a warning like that without having to redefine the whole contact insertion process?